# Creating foreign key constraints in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, foreign-keys, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How do I create foreign keys in ActiveRecord?  I have something like the following in my models:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :level_id
  belongs_to :level
end

class Level < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :number
  has_many :students
end
```

But the schema.rb and development sqlite3 database don't have any indication foreign key constraints were setup with the level_id field.  Is this something I have to do manually apart from ActiveRecord or Rails?  Did I miss a step?

Using Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do not need a foreign key constraints for ActiveRecord to correctly map the relationships. You can use [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validations-overview) to have the Rails app ensure data integrity.

Rails migration do not provider helpers to create foreign keys. You can create your own SQL for the constraint in the migration or use the the [Foreigner Gem](https://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner). Foreigner will provide helper methods for creating constraints in a migration:

```
add_foreign_key(:students, :levels)
```

Comment: The Foreigner gem looks good.  So there's no built-in mechanism to Rails/ActiveRecord for this?

Comment: Sadly no. Migrations will create indexes, but not foreign keys. From  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html - "The references helper does not actually create foreign key constraints for you. You will need to use execute or a plugin that adds foreign key support."

Comment: As stated in another answer, as of rails 4.2 and beyond, there is indeed support for adding foreign key constraints —  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#foreign-key-support

Comment: While the first sentence is true, it does not answer the question. Many developers would agree that having a well constrained db schema is as important, if not more so, than relying on the application to manage integrity, this answer discourages good database design principles and IMO is not helpful.

Answer (score 16):

If you have rails >= 4.2 and using the `mysql`, `mysql2`, or `postgresql` adapter, then you can use the `add_foreign_key` method in your migration like this:

```
# add a foreign key to `articles.author_id` referencing `authors.id`
add_foreign_key :articles, :authors
```

[API Reference](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key)

Answer (score 3):

This is built into Rails now, you don't need Foreigner.  See section 3.6 Foreign Keys here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Comment: This is not built into Rails, Rails mimics this behavior by doing a select query, but a SQL constraint will guarantee referential integrity, it's a good practice to add them.

Comment: You are wrong.  As referenced above, it does create the actual foreign key constraint.  See here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key

Comment: I think I didn't explain correctly, but you're right. What I meant was that Rails does not add foreign keys automatically when adding a reference column, Rails has built-in functions for this, but you need to explicitly tell the migration to create a foreign key or add it by yourself using `add_foreign_key` https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_reference

Answer (score 2):

Adding `belong_to` and `has_many` lines to your models makes Rails aware of their relationship and generates helper methods, but does not create FKs at the database level. To do that, you need to create and run a migration:

```
rails g migration add_level_id_to_students level_id:integer
```

then
    rake db:migrate

If you want to generate a model with the foreign key part of it, you can use the `references` shortcut:
`rails g model Student name:string level:references`

Check out the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for more information!

Comment: I did those already and the relationships work fine.  I'm asking about FKs at the database level.  So by your comment it sounds like this is something I should add outside of Rails/ActiveRecord?

Comment: The question is asking specifically about the database-level constraints that is popular outside of Rails/ActiveRecord.  While this answer specifies what is done in Rails/ActiveRecord, it doesn't address that.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $ rails generate migration AddStudentRefToLevels student:references
```

which should make something like this

```
class AddStudentRefToLevels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :levels, :student, index: true
  end
end
```

taken from here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-migration

Comment: Remember index != foreign key, you need to also add `foreign_key: true`